# Double For Loops Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
for n in range(2, 6):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n // x)
            break
        elif x + 1 == n:
            print(n, 'is a prime number')
```

Result:

```
3 is a prime number 
4 equals 2 * 2 
5 is a prime number
```

Can anybody explain me the double for loop, why does it skip the number 2? Is it because the last number is not included in for x in range (2,2), how does this program work when iterates using 3, I tried doing the second for loop by itself using 3 and i get 2 and on another line 3, so what does it do in the third line with n%x ==0. And what does it do in the 6th line using 3? Thank you I'd appreciate it if you can walk me through this.

Comment: Are you also asking what `%` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for n in range(2, 6):
```

means for n in the numbers 2 up to, but not including 6.
So, start with `n = 2`
The next line says

```
for x in range(2, n):
```

`n` is currently 2, so this means no numbers (from 2 while less than 2).
It then uses the next value for `n`, namely 3.
This will use `range(2,3)` i.e. just the number 2.
And so on.
I suggest initially just seeing what the loops do, without any code to find prime numbers.

```
for n in range(2, 6):
    print n
    for x in range(2, n):
        print x
```

The prime number logic `break`s from the loop if it finds a divisor of `n`

Comment: when you say for x in range(2,3), you get 2 on one line and 3 on another, why is it 3%2 and not 3%3?

Comment: @user2971015 I'm not clear what you mean by 2 on one line and 3 on another